# How to estimate the likelihood that a distribution is not random

Tags: distributions, statistical-significance, likelihood

Not sure I phrase the title right, but here's by question in a nutshell.

Say you have a box of balls with different colors. Let's say there are $N$ balls of $k$ different colors, and that the distribution of colors is such that some colors are more represented than others with a known distribution. You then ask a completely colorblind person to separate the balls across $M$ equally probable bins.

[image]

**What is the likelihood of the distribution of balls made by this colorblind person?** 
Or: how likely is it that the person is *really* colorblind?

So far I've addressed the problem in this line of thought: If the person is completely colorblind, the most likely distribution would be random so it makes sense to somehow compare the outcome to this. If there were infinite balls I would just compare the distribution in each bin to the known distribution of colors, but as $N$ grows smaller this approach reduces in validity. The problem can also be recast such as to say that each bin draws a number of times from the distribution, but it gets very complicated when $N$ is finite because then the draws in each bin influence each other. Not sure how to proceed from here.

**Disclaimer:** This is a simplification of the actual problem I'm working on. Really, I'm studying whether the values a variable assumes in varying distances from a point can be said to have statistical significance, or are just random. The $N$ values of the variable are discretised into $k$ intervals, and distances into $M$ intervals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the problem is laid out it makes me think of a multivariate hypergeometric distribution. It is the same distribution assumed in Fisher's Exact Test.

That distribution models following situation :

> In an urn there are $N$ balls each of a color so that there are $c$ colors. There are $K_i$ balls for color $i$. A sample of size $n$ is taken out of that urn and you end up with $k_i$ balls for each $i$ color so your sample is a vector ($k_1, k_2, ... k_c$).

The probability of such a sample is given by the multivariate hypergeometric distribution :

$P = \frac{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^c {K_i\choose k_i}}{{N \choose n}}$

In a Fisher's Exact Test (FET) for a table of size 2xc you can compute the probability of such a table happening with the multivariate hypergeometric distribution. Now, if you want to know how extreme that table is (*i.e* how not random it is) you have to consider all the other tables with same marginal totals (similar sampling) and compute their probability too. The p-value of that test is then the sum of all the probabilities lesser or equal to the probability of the actual sample/table.

Note that this distribution assume that there is no replacement and a ball is of only one color.

Hope it helps and I was clear

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So in this setting I suppose you draw a sample vector for each bin. The only thing that's troubling here is that if N is finite, the probability distribution changes with each draw right?

Comment: Yeah I would say that each bin is a sample (so multi-multivariate ?). Yep, so I think that for each bin you have to adjust the $K_i$ to match with what is already out (to keep the assumption of no replacement). This way you would consider each bin as a MH sampling from a 'different' urn.

Comment: Sure, but take into account that the samples are drawn in parallel and not necessarily with any particular governing order.

Comment: Hum... Then I guess there is no other way than modeling each sampling, one ball after the other to take that into account. At least none that I know of. But you already mentioned that one and it's going to get really heavy as $N$ grows. Even more so if you want to repeat that process multiple times to compare your situation to other, hypothetical, ones, in a FET-style of test.